# How can I stop someone I know from harassing me online?

Tags: united-kingdom, harassment

My ex partner keeps making new accounts on Instagram and Facebook to message me. I’ve sent them a text with a read receipt that states clearly: don’t contact me on any platform, don’t text me, don’t call me etc. They even had a mutual person call me when they were with them.

I’ve blocked every single account and I haven’t replied to any messages since telling them not to contact me again. I have proof of everything.

The messages are not threatening and this has been going on for less than a month but they have done similar to their previous partner for 9 months and I suspect that they may not leave me alone for the next year.

I want to do something that will force them not to contact me online- and force them not to have other people contact me on their behalf if possible.

How can I stop this from happening? I’m happy to accept an answer that requires them to voluntarily sign something.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118752/discussion-on-question-by-anonymous-how-can-i-stop-someone-i-know-from-harassing).

Comment: What _part_ of the U.K.?  The law in Scotland is different from the law in England, Wales, and Northern Ireland when it comes to this.

Answer (score 19):

Citizens Advice in the UK has some great [advice pages on dealing with harassment](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/law-and-courts/discrimination/taking-action-about-discrimination/taking-action-about-harassment/), but your options are limited - you can't actually stop someone from contacting you, but you can make their actions have consequences.

Try contacting the police, who may speak to the individual in question and that may be enough to stop the harassment, or you can try applying for an injunction against the person in court (commonly called a restraining order).  If the person breaches the injunction, then it can become a criminal matter.

Comment: Great answer. You might want to add a few bits about the consequences of breaching the injunction, e.g. as laid out here: https://rightsofwomen.org.uk/get-information/violence-against-women-and-international-law/harassment-and-the-law/#:~:text=If%20your%20abuser%20is%20found,years%20or%20fined%2C%20or%20both.&text=If%20you%20have%20been%20harassed,application%20to%20the%20county%20court.  Its not enough for me to write a separate answer, but might be a good addition for yours.

Comment: This said, an injunction, protection order, or retaining order is often difficult or impossible to obtain if the repeated contacts are not in fact bona fide threats and don't meet a very high level of disruption to your life. There is not a general legal right to not be contacted by other people just because you tell them not to. Also, while violations of certain special kinds of court orders are criminal offenses, violations of other kinds of court orders (which may be easier to obtain) may constitute civil or criminal contempt of court but are not crimes in the ordinary sense of the word.

Comment: @ohwilleke the link I give is quite in-depth on what actions can be taken, and I think answers most of your concerns.

Comment: @Moo The link is indeed very good. My main point is that in the absence of a threat of violence you must still establish "harassment" which "is when a person behaves in a way which is intended to cause you distress or alarm" and the facts presented are pretty marginal for establishing that point and could go either way. The link while using the term "injunction" for convenience is mostly only talking about injunctions under the harassment act, which is often a good remedy. But there are other grounds upon which you can get a common law injunction if you can't prove harassment in some cases.

Comment: @ohwilleke the UK courts actually take quite a broad view on what constitutes harassment and the criteria for fulfilling it, so its not actually as difficult as it sounds - but your points are noted and worth reading!

Comment: As I noted in a question comment, the law differs in different parts of the U.K..  It is important to note that the hyperlinked advice is, as it says at the top, applicable in England.  There is different advice for Scotland.